Retrieve player_id OneSignal
I've having an issue with my Application. I have setup OneSignal following the tutorial on OneSignal website. Everything is working and now i'm looking to retrieve the unique "player_id" of the device.
All codes I'm finding or the documentation isn't working. Here is a code I have found :
private func getPlayerId() {
    OneSignal.getDeviceState { state in
        if let playerId = state?.userId {
            self.playerId = playerId
            print("Player ID: \(playerId)")
        } else {
            print("Player ID not available")
        }
    }
}

Full code :
import SwiftUI
import OneSignalFramework

struct FormView: View {
    @State private var name: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Nom") ?? ""
    @State private var playerId: String = ""
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Veuillez entrer votre nom")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding()
            
            TextField("Nom", text: $name)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
            
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    saveName()
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Enregistrer")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Retour")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .onAppear {
            getPlayerId()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Inscription")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
    
    private func getPlayerId() {
        OneSignal.getDeviceState { state in
            if let playerId = state?.userId {
                self.playerId = playerId
                print("Player ID: \(playerId)")
            } else {
                print("Player ID not available")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func saveName() {
        // Enregistrer le nom localement
        UserDefaults.standard.set(name, forKey: "Nom")
        print("Nom enregistré : \(name)")
        
        // Envoyer le nom à une URL en arrière-plan
        sendNameToServer(name: name)
    }
    
    private func sendNameToServer(name: String) {
        // Encoder le nom en Base64
        let data = name.data(using: .utf8)
        let base64EncodedName = data?.base64EncodedString() ?? ""
        
        // Construire l'URL avec le nom encodé en Base64
        let urlString = "https://mywebsiteaaa.com/nux.php?accueil:::::::::::::\(base64EncodedName):\(playerId)"
        
        // Créer l'URL complète
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("URL invalide")
            return
        }
        
        // Créer une requête HTTP
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        // Créer une tâche de session pour envoyer les données
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Erreur lors de l'envoi des données : \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                print("Réponse inattendue du serveur")
                return
            }
            
            // Traitement des données de réponse si nécessaire
            if let data = data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Réponse du serveur : \(responseString)")
            }
        }
        
        // Démarrer la tâche
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct FormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormView()
    }
}

I get error in Xcode : Type 'OneSignal' has no member 'getDeviceState'
Below a screenshot on my Xcode to have a better view of the situation :


It’s a function, you need a pair of parentheses. Something like let state = OneSignal.getDeviceState()

@JoakimDanielson I'm new with swift and onesignal. May you correct my code in an answer please? I'm a bit lost...
